# Использование переменных (выражения concat()) в генерации дат в цикле Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Наполнение таблицы

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_table_foo()
    RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE

    startId INT;
    endId   INT;
    nameVar TEXT;
    dateVar TIMESTAMP;
    period INT default 0;
begin
    startId := 1;
    endId := 20;

    for idVar in startId..endId
        loop

            nameVar := md5(random()::text);
            dateVar := (now()::timestamp with time zone + concat(3 + ' hour')::interval + concat(period, ' day')::interval );

            insert into foo(id, name, data) values (idVar, nameVar, dateVar);

            period := period + 1;

        end loop;
end ;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Вот эта строчка

```sql
        dateVar := (now()::timestamp with time zone + concat(3 + ' hour')::interval + concat(period, ' day')::interval );
```

не отрабатывает, когда я пытаюсь использовать переменные в выражении concat().

**period** - этот счетчик не учитывается.

Эта строка работает только так :

```sql
 dateVar := ( now()::timestamp with time zone + '3 hour'::interval + '5 day'::interval );
```

Но я хотел бы подставлять переменные вместо 3 и 5 , так как это переменные величины в цикле. Может кто знает как это сделать ?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь функцией make_interval https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/functions-datetime

Comment: А `concat(3 + ' hour')` конечно не отработает, аргументы функции разделяются запятой, а не знаком `+`

Comment: Прямо вот `make_interval(hours=>3, days=>1)` где вместо 3 и 1 могут быть переменные конечно

Comment: Решение нужно писать в ответ, а не в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_table_foo()
    RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE

    startId      INT;
    endId        INT;
    nameVar      TEXT;
    dateVar      TIMESTAMP;
    period       INT default 0;
    stepTimeZone INT default 0;
begin
    startId := 1;
    endId := 20;

    for idVar in startId..endId
        loop
            nameVar := md5(random()::text);
            stepTimeZone := 3;
            dateVar :=
                    (now()::timestamp with time zone +
                     make_interval(hours := stepTimeZone) +
                     make_interval(days := period)
                        );

            insert into foo(id, name, data) values (idVar, nameVar, dateVar);

            period := period + 1;
        end loop;
end ;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```